# Is there any ACTUAL updated documentation about android style adjustment?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, material-design, android-styles

I have a big problem with styles. I spent 2 days looking for a working solution to adjust the colors of pickers and alerts. I can't find any documentation about XML attributes of themes and styles. For example I don't able to find any actual documentation about which color depends on which attribute for pickers dialogs. Is there any official actual tutorial about android styling? Especially for picker and alert dialogs.

Comment: this might be useful for you https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any official actual tutorial about android styling? Especially for picker and alert dialogs.

For Alert dialogs style,you can take a look the following steps

1.Create Alert style in Values folder-styles.xml

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
<item name="colorAccent">#FFCC00</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
<item name="android:background">#5fa3d0</item>
```

2. Using this style for Alert dialogs.

   ```
    Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
    Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this, Resource.Style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
           builder.SetTitle("Dialog");
           builder.SetMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,");
           builder.SetPositiveButton("OK", (c, ev) =>
           {
               // Ok button click task  
           });
           builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (c, ev) =>
           {
               // cancel button click task  
           });
           builder.Show();
   ```

I also find one article about this:

http://gmariotti.blogspot.com/2015/04/a-material-styled-alertdialog.html

About Picker control, it is a Xamarin.forms control? There are DatePicker, NumberPicker or other, I don't find Picker.